# set-guid exploit of a program with relative path

Tags: privilege-escalation, unix

I'm trying to exploit a program which has the set-guid bit enabled. The program is simple it contains the following (stage.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  gid_t egid = getegid();
  setregid(egid, egid);

  system("cat /etc/passwd");
  return 0;
}
```

I need to call a program called "grade" with the group of the given program. I can't create new files. What can I do?

Comment: You can't create new files **anywhere** at all? Can you rename files?

Comment: No I can't. I have to use the privilege of stage to call grade and to change the directory to /home/stage3/

Comment: Did you try aliasing cat to grade and setting path to be the directory that contains the grade program?

Comment: Never mind, looks like `system()` doesn't keep alias commands. Unless you have a symlink called `cat` that points to your grade program you'll need to find some other way to make it call grade explicitly.

Comment: Your question title says "relative path" but your code contains only an absolute path (technically the #includes are relative paths but I'm guessing you don't get to recompile the program). Is there actually a relative path somewhere? `cat` isn't a path, at least not how Unix shells interpret it; you'd need it to be something like `,/cat` for that. I suppose your $PATH could contain `./` but even then, if you can't create or rename files... Also, "GUID" is a different thing from "UID" and "GID" (you're using GID here), and there's no such thing as a "set-guid" bit (I assume you mean set-gid?).